# Entity Framework Core: Generate 'Create' and 'Update' script of Entity

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to generate 'Create' and 'Update' script of some database object in Entity Framework Core

```
    public class Cat
    {
        public int CatId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class CatsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new CatsContext())
            {
                var cat = new Cat {Name = "Bob", Age = 15};
                context.Add(cat);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var context = new CatsContext())
            {
                var cat =  context.Set<Cat>().First(); //suppose cat != null, and CatId = 123
                var insertScript = GetInsertScript(); // something like INSERT INTO [Cats] (Name, Age) VALUES ('Bob', 15)
                var updateScript = GetUpdateScript(); // something like UPDATE [Cats] SET Name = 'Bob', Age = 15 WHERE CatId = 123
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I generate this scripts in code? Maybe EF has some native tool, or I shoud use side library?

I know about Migrations and command 'dotnet ef migrations script', but I dont need to create migration, only create and update scripts of some object, existing in database

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Igor my goal is to generate Create or Update scripts from some entity of context